# Usage of Dense(Fully Connected) Layer in Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I know that a dense layer means a classic fully connected layer, which means each input is going to each neuron for multiplication. But recently some questions raised in my mind which when searched on youtube, blogs, StackOverflow, articles nobody gave me a satisfying answer to it.

1-Why do we need fully connected(dense) layers in neural networks, its usage? Can't we use sparse layers(means some input are going to only some neurons so all neurons are not getting all input)

2-What will happen if we use sparse layers? I know computations will be less but what will be the effect on output. Will neuron be able to perform just like dense layers or not.

3-Which will be better sparse or dense layers to use in a neural network.(Pros and Cons)

4- If we can use sparse layer and it performs well then why have I not heard this term more than FCN(Fully connected layer)

Sparse layer is not the same as a drop layer in neural network. In drop layer you prune/drop some neurons but other neurons get all the output from previous layer. So not same.

Answer (score 0):

Using sparse layers would simply introduce more features you would have to tweak. What would your sparse layer look like, what connects to what? Using Dense Layers atleast guarantees that there might be a chance that a connection is used.

You also answer you own question, evidently sparse layers are not better, else you would have heard from them. Dropout on the other hand is useful and is used widely.